# Reading columns between empty lines

Tags: python

Say the data in file is formatted like so:

```
1 4 5
2 3 4
4 7 1

1 1 1
2 1 2
3 3 3
4 1 4

2 2 2
```

and I always want to read portions of the data between empty lines, e.g. I want the columns between the first empty line and the second empty line, so v1 = [1,2,3,4], v2 = [1,1,3,1] and so on. 
First thing I do I find the indices of where the empty lines occur by:

```
filetmp = open('data.txt')
indices = []
for i, line in enumerate(filetmp):
    tmp = ''.join(c for c in line if c.isalnum() or c.isspace())
    print tmp
    if not tmp.strip(): indices.append(i)
```

Now `indices` indeed contains the right indices, i.e. of empty lines. Next part, is to read the wanted parts, given the indices of empty lines, so that we can fill v1, v2 etc. Should I do this by doing a `filetmp.readlines()` first? or are there more straightforward ways of reading specific parts, when dealing with columns of data?

Comment: Maybe you can also use pandas read_tab. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html. You can then fetch only the data between two NaN rows. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @pmaniyan of course all suggestions are welcome, thanks so much. Indeed others have told me to try such things with panda, I guess it s time to take up on it. Would you be so kind to showcase how it could be used in such context? (would definitely be useful to future readers as well)

Comment: You could always just split() it first by newline, then by space, and go from there. The main disadvantage is it'll load the entire dataset into memory first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd this as follow:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

v = []
# Split the string into blocks, by looking for duplicated line terminaters ('\n\n').
for i, block in enumerate(data.split('\n\n')):
    # Split the blocks in lines by looking for line terminaters ('\n').
    lines = block.split('\n')
    v.append([])
    for line in lines:
        if line == "":
            continue
        v[i] += [line.split(' ')]

# Take the middle block and transpose it.
v1 = map(list, zip(*v[1]))
```

Of course you can only work with the second block instead of iterating over all.

As a function:

```
def get_block_from_file(file_path, block_number):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        data = f.read()

    blocks = data.split('\n\n')
    try:
        block = blocks[block_number - 1]
    except IndexError:
        print('Not enough blocks')
        import sys; sys.exit(1)
    v = []
    lines = block.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if line == "":
            continue
        v += [map(int, line.split(' '))]

    return map(list, zip(*v))

print(get_block_from_file('data.txt', 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it looks so complicated to follow. I m going to try it now and see if I understand the details well.

Comment: Be careful with large files, since it's reading the entire file into memory first.

Comment: Awesome! two small questions: i) is it possible to extract the data as it is, without transforming to string? e.g. right now, if a column is 1, 2, 0.2 ... the extracted comes as ['1','2','0.2'] instead of [1,2,0.2]. ii) everytime get_block_from_file returns, the opened file is closed and emptied from memory, right?

Comment: I edited the code, it now returns list with integers.
The file is only open when you read the data (http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-code-patterns/maintainability/not_using_with_to_open_files.html). But the content is still in data and also in blocks.

Comment: Thanks, neat! Don't mean to be nitpicky, but what if there are mixtures of floats and ints? is there a more general replacement for map(..., line.split(' ')?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. This is using Pandas. This is to fit to your current dataset. If you have multiple blanks lines (more than 2), then you might have to loop through for finding the l_lower_index and l_upper_index

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l_df = pd.read_table('expt2data.txt',sep=' ',header=None,names=('Col_1','Col_2','Col_3'), skip_blank_lines=False)

l_lower_index = l_df[l_df['Col_1'].isnull()].index.values[0]
l_upper_index = l_df[l_df['Col_1'].isnull()].index.values[1]
v1 = l_df.ix[l_lower_index + 1:l_upper_index - 1]['Col_1'].values
v2 = l_df.ix[l_lower_index + 1:l_upper_index - 1]['Col_2'].values
print v1
print v2
```

**Output**

```
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
[ 1.  1.  3.  1.]
```

**expt2data.txt**

```
1 4 5
2 3 4
4 7 1

1 1 1
2 1 2
3 3 3
4 1 4

2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I seem to get an error with unexpected keyword argument for 'skip_blank_lines'. Is this by any chance for python 3? I have py 2.7

Comment: Mine is also Python 2.7 and Pandas is 0.17.1. This code is working for me without any errors. Please share your code and error trace.